# STM32H743 MDMA can't access APB2

Tags: stm32, memory, dma, cortex-m, cortex-m7

I have a code that mdma can access any variable feed to it by &var (AXI SRAM) also I have gave it an address of ADC common registers from APB1 but adress from APB2 &hrng.Instance.DR causes HAL_xfer_read_error. Any idea? I know in reference manual it told access to rng (random number generator) must to be single 32-bit. I've setted 4 byte data length with word data size. But I think maybe this is because of memory region.

And the code (this code runs well but change &buffy to &hrng.Instance->DR reproduce the problem):

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2022 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

RNG_HandleTypeDef hrng;

SAI_HandleTypeDef hsai_BlockA2;
SAI_HandleTypeDef hsai_BlockB2;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_sai2_a;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_sai2_b;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_usart1_tx;

MDMA_HandleTypeDef hmdma_mdma_channel40_dma1_stream0_tc_0;
/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
__IO uint32_t noise=10000;
__IO uint32_t buffy=0x10101010;
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_SAI2_Init(void);
static void MX_RNG_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_MDMA_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_SAI2_Init();
  MX_RNG_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  MX_MDMA_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  HAL_MDMA_Start_IT(&hmdma_mdma_channel40_dma1_stream0_tc_0,
          &buffy,
          &noise,
          4,
          1);

  if(HAL_SAI_Transmit_DMA(&hsai_BlockA2, &noise, 1) != HAL_OK) // Generate noise
                      {/* Start Conversation Error */HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED_GPIO_Port,LED_Pin);Error_Handler();}




  while (1)
  {

      HAL_Delay(400);
      buffy=40;
      HAL_Delay(400);
      buffy=0x10101010;


    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Supply configuration update enable
  */
  HAL_PWREx_ConfigSupply(PWR_LDO_SUPPLY);

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE2);

  while(!__HAL_PWR_GET_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_VOSRDY)) {}

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI48|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_CSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSI48State = RCC_HSI48_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.CSIState = RCC_CSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.CSICalibrationValue = RCC_CSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_CSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 75;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = 2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 3;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = 2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLRGE = RCC_PLL1VCIRANGE_2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLVCOSEL = RCC_PLL1VCOWIDE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLFRACN = 0;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_D3PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_D1PCLK1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB3CLKDivider = RCC_APB3_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_APB1_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_APB2_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB4CLKDivider = RCC_APB4_DIV2;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief RNG Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_RNG_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RNG_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END RNG_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RNG_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END RNG_Init 1 */
  hrng.Instance = RNG;
  hrng.Init.ClockErrorDetection = RNG_CED_ENABLE;
  if (HAL_RNG_Init(&hrng) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN RNG_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END RNG_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief SAI2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_SAI2_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SAI2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SAI2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SAI2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SAI2_Init 1 */
  hsai_BlockA2.Instance = SAI2_Block_A;
  hsai_BlockA2.Init.AudioMode = SAI_MODEMASTER_TX;
  hsai_BlockA2.Init.Synchro = SAI_ASYNCHRONOUS;
  hsai_BlockA2.Init.OutputDrive = SAI_OUTPUTDRIVE_ENABLE;
  hsai_BlockA2.Init.NoDivider = SAI_MASTERDIVIDER_ENABLE;
  hsai_BlockA2.Init.FIFOThreshold = SAI_FIFOTHRESHOLD_EMPTY;
  hsai_BlockA2.Init.AudioFrequency = SAI_AUDIO_FREQUENCY_44K;
  hsai_BlockA2.Init.SynchroExt = SAI_SYNCEXT_DISABLE;
  hsai_BlockA2.Init.MonoStereoMode = SAI_MONOMODE;
  hsai_BlockA2.Init.CompandingMode = SAI_NOCOMPANDING;
  hsai_BlockA2.Init.TriState = SAI_OUTPUT_NOTRELEASED;
  if (HAL_SAI_InitProtocol(&hsai_BlockA2, SAI_I2S_STANDARD, SAI_PROTOCOL_DATASIZE_16BIT, 2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  hsai_BlockB2.Instance = SAI2_Block_B;
  hsai_BlockB2.Init.AudioMode = SAI_MODEMASTER_RX;
  hsai_BlockB2.Init.Synchro = SAI_ASYNCHRONOUS;
  hsai_BlockB2.Init.OutputDrive = SAI_OUTPUTDRIVE_DISABLE;
  hsai_BlockB2.Init.NoDivider = SAI_MASTERDIVIDER_ENABLE;
  hsai_BlockB2.Init.FIFOThreshold = SAI_FIFOTHRESHOLD_EMPTY;
  hsai_BlockB2.Init.AudioFrequency = SAI_AUDIO_FREQUENCY_44K;
  hsai_BlockB2.Init.SynchroExt = SAI_SYNCEXT_DISABLE;
  hsai_BlockB2.Init.MonoStereoMode = SAI_STEREOMODE;
  hsai_BlockB2.Init.CompandingMode = SAI_NOCOMPANDING;
  if (HAL_SAI_InitProtocol(&hsai_BlockB2, SAI_I2S_STANDARD, SAI_PROTOCOL_DATASIZE_16BIT, 2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SAI2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END SAI2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief USART1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 1 */
  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 1000000;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart1.Init.ClockPrescaler = UART_PRESCALER_DIV1;
  huart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetTxFifoThreshold(&huart1, UART_TXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetRxFifoThreshold(&huart1, UART_RXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_DisableFifoMode(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
static void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{

  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA1_Stream1_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Stream1_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Stream1_IRQn);
  /* DMA1_Stream3_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Stream3_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Stream3_IRQn);

}

/**
  * Enable MDMA controller clock
  * Configure MDMA for global transfers
  *   hmdma_mdma_channel40_dma1_stream0_tc_0
  */
static void MX_MDMA_Init(void)
{

  /* MDMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_MDMA_CLK_ENABLE();
  /* Local variables */

  /* Configure MDMA channel MDMA_Channel0 */
  /* Configure MDMA request hmdma_mdma_channel40_dma1_stream0_tc_0 on MDMA_Channel0 */
  hmdma_mdma_channel40_dma1_stream0_tc_0.Instance = MDMA_Channel0;
  hmdma_mdma_channel40_dma1_stream0_tc_0.Init.Request = MDMA_REQUEST_DMA1_Stream0_TC;
  hmdma_mdma_channel40_dma1_stream0_tc_0.Init.TransferTriggerMode = MDMA_REPEAT_BLOCK_TRANSFER;
  hmdma_mdma_channel40_dma1_stream0_tc_0.Init.Priority = MDMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
  hmdma_mdma_channel40_dma1_stream0_tc_0.Init.Endianness = MDMA_LITTLE_ENDIANNESS_PRESERVE;
  hmdma_mdma_channel40_dma1_stream0_tc_0.Init.SourceInc = MDMA_SRC_INC_DISABLE;
  hmdma_mdma_channel40_dma1_stream0_tc_0.Init.DestinationInc = MDMA_DEST_INC_DISABLE;
  hmdma_mdma_channel40_dma1_stream0_tc_0.Init.SourceDataSize = MDMA_SRC_DATASIZE_WORD;
  hmdma_mdma_channel40_dma1_stream0_tc_0.Init.DestDataSize = MDMA_DEST_DATASIZE_WORD;
  hmdma_mdma_channel40_dma1_stream0_tc_0.Init.DataAlignment = MDMA_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hmdma_mdma_channel40_dma1_stream0_tc_0.Init.BufferTransferLength = 4;
  hmdma_mdma_channel40_dma1_stream0_tc_0.Init.SourceBurst = MDMA_SOURCE_BURST_SINGLE;
  hmdma_mdma_channel40_dma1_stream0_tc_0.Init.DestBurst = MDMA_DEST_BURST_SINGLE;
  hmdma_mdma_channel40_dma1_stream0_tc_0.Init.SourceBlockAddressOffset = 0;
  hmdma_mdma_channel40_dma1_stream0_tc_0.Init.DestBlockAddressOffset = 0;
  if (HAL_MDMA_Init(&hmdma_mdma_channel40_dma1_stream0_tc_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /* Configure post request address and data masks */
  if (HAL_MDMA_ConfigPostRequestMask(&hmdma_mdma_channel40_dma1_stream0_tc_0, 0x40020008, 0x20) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /* MDMA interrupt initialization */
  /* MDMA_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(MDMA_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(MDMA_IRQn);

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, LED_Pin|LED1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : Push_Pin Push1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = Push_Pin|Push1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : LED_Pin LED1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LED_Pin|LED1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big reason the DMA isn't transferring is that it isn't actually connected to the peripheral.

In most Cortex implementations I've seen, there are multiple memory buses. The ST implementation isn't any different. You can see how the RNG is attached to the chip's memory system in the table below (found in the Memory map section of the [reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00314099-stm32h742-stm32h743-753-and-stm32h750-value-line-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf)).

[image: RNG Memory Location and Bus Attachment]

The missing tap at AHB2 mean that, no matter how you program the DMA, it can't actually access AHB2 and consequently the RNG registers, the physical connections aren't present.

[image: DMA memory taps]

The reason that is important is because DMA controllers are usually implemented with specific use cases in mind. For example, the DMA2D unit is implemented with memory-to-memory transfers in mind. You can tell because of the bus-matrix tap points on most buses.

You'll have to figure out some kind of staging mechanism, maybe you can chain DMAs together or use one of the DMA units that can tap all the peripherals you're interested in.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. Finally I've used Dma request generator, and that done the work.